# Cannot call value of non-function type '[Ingredient]'

Tags: swift, foreach

I am receiving the error Cannot call value of non-function type '[Ingredient]’, and can’t figure out why.

My Recipe class, created in Main.xcdatamodeld, includes many pieces of data about any recipe, including
name: String

I have a file creating an extension to Recipe, which includes:

```
extension Recipe {

    enum SortOrder {
        case title, category
    }

    var recipeName: String {
        name ?? ""
    }

    var recipeIngredients: [Ingredient] {
        ingredients?.allObjects as? [Ingredient] ?? []
    }
}
```

I have a struct RecipeListView, which calls RecipeDetailView.  The call to RecipeDetailView is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RecipeListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State private var sortOrder = Recipe.SortOrder.title

    let recipes: FetchRequest<Recipe>

    init() {
        recipes = FetchRequest<Recipe>(entity: Recipe.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Recipe.name, ascending: true)
        ])
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(recipes.wrappedValue) { recipe in
                        NavigationLink(destination:
RecipeDetailView(recipe: recipe)) {
                            Text(recipe.recipeName)
                                .padding([.horizontal])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Recipes")
        }
    }
}
```

In RecipeDetailView, I am trying to list the ingredients for the chosen recipe (the one passed in), as:

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct RecipeDetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @State private var sortOrder = Recipe.SortOrder.title
    
    var recipe: Recipe

    init (recipe: Recipe) {
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack {
                Section() {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(recipe.recipeIngredients(using: sortOrder)) { ingredient in
                            Text("\(ingredient.name)")
                    }
// lots of other recipe content snipped here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the ForEach line, I am getting the error (with the marker under the c in recipeIngredients), but recipe is passed in by the call, and recipe.recipeIngredients and sortOrder are defined in the extension.  And, ingredient.name is defined in Main.xcdatamodeld.
I have tried adding a line to init as “var chosenRecipe = recipe” and then using chosenRecipe.recipeIngredients in the ForEach.  I have tried recipe.ingredient and recipe.recipeIngredient as what is going in for the ForEach.  I have tried doing the ForEach on recipe.ingredients, and ingredients.  All to no avail.  It seems as if the error is telling me I need a function call in my ForEach, which makes no sense. Any help appreciated.
Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

You have a property

```
var recipeIngredients: [Ingredient] {
    ingredients?.allObjects as? [Ingredient] ?? []
}
```

but in your ForEach you are calling it like it is a function

```
ForEach(recipe.recipeIngredients(using: sortOrder)) {
```

so the error message makes very much sense. So to start with change it to

```
ForEach(recipe.recipeIngredients) {
```

and have it sorted earlier or do something like

```
ForEach(recipe.recipeIngredients.sorted(by: { <your sort logic here> }) {
```

Comment: @BillDay any feedback on this?